# Laptop HDMI port not working

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, sony-vaio

I have Sony VAIO laptop with additional monitor connected with HDMI -> DVI cable. 
Everything seemed to work perfectly fine until today morning. I had computer with own display and second monitor working after connecting.

Today there is no signal sent from computer to monitor. Doesn't matter if i choose extend or duplicate desktop. The computer recognizes new equipment installed, I can see it in resolution settings, additionaly I can move my cursor out of laptop display to second monitor (that is black, not receiving signal).

After connecting the same monitor (with the same cable) to another laptop - monitor works. 
After connecting another monitor to Sony VAIO with the same cable - monitor recognized by computer as previous but still black screen with 'No signal' info.

I suppose that my HDMI port is not sending any signal. I am wondering if there is a way to find a reason for that. Could this be some software malfunction or it is probably hardware defect and I will have to send it to service?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried another cable and another adapter by chance?  You don't indicate what operating system.

Comment: Of course. The VAIO is Windows 8. The other one is windows 7.

I tried only this cable but wit two different computers and cable worked with another computer (same monitor) so probably the problem is in the port.